# Include js/css in Liferay DXP JSP Hook (module fragment)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am working on Liferay DXP SP3 with fix pack 24 installed. I have created a module fragment project to override (hook) the edit_permissions JSP. I have CSS and Javascript that is very specific to this custom JSP so I would like to include it with the module rather than with the theme. Based on [this documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/theme-contributors), it sounds like I should be able to do this by making the module a "theme contributor" module. I have set the `Liferay-Theme-Contributor-Type` and `Web-ContextPath` attributes in the bnd.bnd file, like this:

```
Liferay-Theme-Contributor-Type: portlet.config.jsp.overrides
Web-ContextPath: /edit-permissions-theme-contributor
```

I have created a `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/js` folder and placed my custom javascript files in this folder. It is my understanding that with this configuration I should be able to include the custom javascript files in my JSP hook using a regular script tag with a path like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/o/edit-permissions-theme-contributor/js/my-custom-script.js"></script>`

I have tried many variations of the URL (with and without the "o", etc.). However, I always get a 404 on my script file. Am I doing this incorrectly? Is there a better way to include static files in a fragment module?

Comment: Are you mixing the jsp hook bundle with the contributor bundle? How many jar files do you have?

Comment: It is just a jsp hook (I believe they call it a fragment project in DXP). So there is only one module. I just have some javascript that is very specific to this jsp hook so I want to include it in the bundle, not with my theme.  I would like to put it in a js file so it can get cached by the browser rather than inline it on the JSP.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas I have only one jar file, just the JSP fragment. I was under the impression that I had to use the "theme contributor" configuration in the bnd.bnd file to get my static resources exposed as part of the portal's web app at something like /o/my-context-path-here.

Comment: try to split it into 2 bundles. The JSP into a fragment bundle and the java class in a proper bundle.

Comment: @MiroslavLigas thanks, I'm sure that will work, I was just hoping to keep the js bundled together with the module since it is very specific to the jsp fragment. If it has to be in two bundles, I'll probably just push the js up to the theme. This is a very large project so we have quite a few jsp fragments and it would be nice to keep the number of modules down if possible (we're already up to 32 modules).

Comment: don't be too afraid of many modules and it better to keep stuff in the modules than in the theme. It's more flexible and also you have more options with that.
In general, fragments are not real bundles that can be activated so you cant start them and classes are not processed. There are ways how to work around it. Have a look at this. https://dzone.com/articles/osgi-fragment-bundles-dont